# Copying values from file to main function variables so they can be used

Tags: c

I open up a .txt file using a function, the file contains the number 3.0.

Then in main, I want to set this variable -> read in from the file _> copy the value from the pointer to the variable. I'm printing to check.

```
void fileview(double *C);

int main(void) {
    double *C_p;

    fileview(*C_p);

    double C;
    C = *C_p;

    printf("%f", C);
    printf("%p", C_p);
    return 0;
}

void fileview(double *C) {
   FILE *infile;
   if(!(infile=fopen("input.txt","r"))) {
       printf("Error opening file\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   if(1!=fscanf(infile,"%lf",C)) {
       printf("Error reading parameters from file\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   fclose(infile);
}
```

I thought this would make sense because at first the I state the value at the pointer. Then I input the value from the pointer through the file. Then I put the value from the pointer into a variable C.

But I get errors:

error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘fileview’
     fileview(*C_p);

note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘double’
 void fileview(double *C);

Comment: You’ll have to give it the pointer and not dereference it. Also the pointer doesn’t point to anywhere so using it is undefined behavior

Answer (score 2):

The problem is how you make this call:

```
fileview(*C_p);
```

The function `fileview` expects a `double *` but `*C_p` is a `double`.

But you have an even bigger problem. `C_p` is uninitialised and you're dereferencing it here - this is [undefined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
In `filevew()`, it writes to `*C` as if it points to valid memory.

You could simply write your `main` as:

```
int main(void) {
    double C = 0;

    fileview(&C);

    printf("%f", C);
    return 0;
}
```

which ensures a valid pointer is passed to `fileview()`.

Your `fileview` contains an issue too: `fscanf()` returns the number of *items* successfully scanned. So you should be checking it against 1 when you scan for a single `double` value:

```
  if( 1! = fscanf(infile,"%lf",C) ) {
      ...
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`fileview()` expects a pointer to a double variable as its argument. `C_p` is a `double *`, so `*C_p` is just a `double`, not a `double *`.

You need to set the pointer to point to valid memory, so it needs to hold the address of `C` *before* you call `fileview()`.

```
void fileview(double *C);

int main(void) {
    double C;
    double *C_p = &C;

    fileview(C_p);

    printf("%f", C);
    printf("%p", C_p);
    return 0;
}

void fileview(double *C) {
   FILE *infile;
   if(!(infile=fopen("input.txt","r"))) {
       printf("Error opening file\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   if(5!=fscanf(infile,"%lf",C)) {
       printf("Error reading parameters from file\n");
       exit(1);
   }
   fclose(infile);
}
```